# Run python code with terminal, from anywhere

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new with Ubuntu and I can't seem to make my python program work with the terminal from anywhere in the computer.

Here what I did so far :

- first line of my code : #!/usr/bin/python
- terminal : chmod +x archiveur.py
- terminal : sudo cp archiveur.py /usr/local/bin

and now everytime I write my command in terminal, it tell me the command is not found.

How I can call my command atm :

> python archiveur.py arg1 arg2

How I actually want to call it :

> archiveur arg1 arg2

Anything I did wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give the results of "which python" because you should run your program simply by typing the following command "python archiveur.py"

Comment: /usr/bin/python
I need to execute my program without writing "python archiveur.py" just "archiveur arg1 arg2 ..."

Comment: type in terminal where there is archiveur program "./archiveur.py arg1 arg2

Comment: Edited the thread as I realized there was missing a info, I actually need to call my command like this : archiveur arg1 arg2.
It for a homework and that the last part I am missing, I managed to do it on windows using a .bat but I have no idea how Ubuntu work for creating a command.

Comment: @MaxyArthes...its totally bad for asking homework here....but for your orientashion...you need to create an alias in your bashrc file ...or write a bash scripts and name it archiveur that will in turn pass the argument to your python script